# Размещение блоков при изменении страницы

Tags: html, css, javascript

Пишу свой скроллер. На рисунке его схема.

Черный прямоугольник - основная область. Зеленый прямоугольник - сам скроллер. Красный область данных.
Ширина зеленого 10px, а высота 100%. Размер черного 100% на 100%.
Вокруг его также еще один div, в котором я указываю общий размер всей конструкции.

Задача: правильно указать размер красного.

Все бы нечего, если бы не размер страницы, потому что с изменениям размера страницы меняется меняется общий размер конструкции

Вы можете сказать: "так меняй и размер красного". Здесь есть одно но: такой скроллер будет использоваться много раз и получится, что сам код js будет замусорен вот этими подсчетами размером.

К чему я веду: можно указать, что размер красного и зеленого 90% на 10%, но это будет не совсем правильно. Как указать, что ширина зеленого 10px, а красного - остальное пространство? Без js это возможно?

[image]

Comment: про ширину можно так: [display: table-row](http://jsfiddle.net/4xYrs/)

Comment: @eicto почти оно, но теперь не можно указать высоту http://jsfiddle.net/4xYrs/3/

Comment: @andrey3, больно часто тут стали употреблять фразу "не можно"), это что такой новый стиль разговорной речи или забыли про слово "нельзя"?

Comment: @andrey3, в дополнение к ответу @eicto:  
Да, вы не можете задать высоту табличной строки. Однако вы можете задать высоту ячейки в этой строке или высоту самой таблицы.  
Мысль улавливаете?

Сделайте блок-обертку таблицей:  

    .wrap {
        display: table;
    }

Поскольку сейчас внутри этой таблицы у нас только 1 строка - она растянется на всю ее высоту.

http://jsfiddle.net/4xYrs/4/

Comment: @VenZell спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожно попробовать красный блок отодвинуть padding на размер скролла, т.е. если

```
.green {position: fixed; width: 200px}
.red {padding: 0 210px 0 0}
```

Ну это если фиксированный блок, хотя можно и не с фиксированным сделать.

Можно кстати глянуть пример размещения колонок сидебара в генераторе html5 http://csstemplater.com/
Просто вместо правой колонки использовать колонку для скролла. Так как раз по моему то что вам нужно.

---

Style.css

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

.middle {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.middle:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    padding: 0 270px 0 0;
}

.scroll {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFACAA;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="middle">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="scroll">
            scroll
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @webphp если я поставлю внутри черного padding справа 10px, то зеленый не станет. Вот http://jsfiddle.net/wKq88/ как я могу подправить?